# Any difference between „sich mit den Kindern beschäftigen“ and „sich um die Kinder kümmern“?

Tags: meaning, difference

Both phrases mean *taking care of one's children*, but I wonder whether there is any difference in nuance between them?

Comment: Related: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/17400/

Answer (score 10):

I disagree that both sentences can be translated as "taking care of the children". Note that in both cases you have to translate with *the* children and not *one's* children. There is no connotation in the German sentences regarding *which* children are acted with/upon.

The first sentence "sich mit den Kindern beschäftigen" has a more specific meaning, saying that you engage in some sort of activity with or for the children (beschäftigen -> occupy, engage).  The second sentence "sich um die Kinder kümmern" has a wider sense and can be translated as "taking care of the children", but does not require an active part on your side.

For example, if you sit reading a book, having just an eye on your playing children, you do "dich um die Kinder kümmern", but you do not "dich mit den Kindern beschäftigen".

Comment: Note that "sich um die Kinder kümmern" can even work in absence and without contact, simply meaning financial support, for example.

Comment: thanks for your answer, should i interpret ,,sich beschäftigen mit jm." as 'engage oneself as sb.'s company' or 'devote oneself to handling  sb.'s matter/affairs'?